# Is there a way to empty the session file with PHP?

Tags: php, session

I'm wondering if I can destroy/modify sessions in a native PHP way that doesn't involve file I/O directives.

I'm not talking about $_SESSION, *I mean access to the session files themselves*.

For instance, PHP stores sessions on linux as files:

```
@lamp:/var/lib/php5$ ls
sess_301dc8935f1775312e9007431782c68b
sess_6892f0bec257e646d193adfd91233c40
sess_966909941003dd6fd333727d8862be6e
sess_cb7c07117cef89674a686ffff8a730f2
sess_ffb4db1d9002741b7e0fcc02090b9aaa
sess_305aeb0fdba7548e389394cb31d77c3b
.... etc
```

$_SESSION gives us the value of what's inside a current session, and the `session_start()` and `session_destroy()` will terminate the current session identifier.

I want to know if I can destroy or modify sessions globally in a native way to php that doesn't resort to me having to do `fopen(/var/lib/php5/sess_whatever)`, I don't want to work with the current session, I want a script to be able to either delete or modify sessions outside of what `$_SESSION`, `session_start`, and `session_stop` do, as they force you to use the present session.

Comment: $_SESSION & how it's handled is part of PHP, Apache's job is only to pass cookie/session_id info to PHP. PHP can implement sessions in different ways, not just via files (e.g. MySQL, Memcache). This might be helpful if you're trying to kill sessions other than the active session, as it might be cleaner to interface with a database than with the file system. You will probably get a performance boost as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you can't have it both ways. Session handling functions are built to interact with the current session. In order to manipulate other sessions you will have to go the whole fopen() route.

Answer (score 3):

[`session_destroy`](http://php.net/session_destroy) does that:

> `session_destroy()` destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.

Comment: That destroys the current session, yes, but again I want to be able to either delete or modify globally, not the data in $_SESSION. Again, this is the file of session I want to modify if there are native PHP commands to do such, rather than limited to current session, without doing something like `fopen('../data/sessions.../session3958912')`

Comment: @user257493: But this *does* destroy only the stored session data and not the session data in `$_SESSION`. Then what else do you want to do?

Comment: @user257493: Ok, now I see. You want to modify/destroy any arbitrary session and not only the current session. Well then, no, there is no build-in function that does that.